# Сокращение кода. Сократить команду, символы

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Забыл команду, чтобы можно было

```
bind MynumclassAlwaysneedToPrintAllsymbols=>MA
```

Чтобы в коде не набирать постоянно MynumclassAlwaysneedToPrintAllsymbols, а сокращенное MA:

```
//Вместо
MynumclassAlwaysneedToPrintAllsymbols.MyMethod1();
//Можно было короче:
MA.MyMethod1();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using MA=MynumclassAlwaysneedToPrintAllsymbols;
```